# Is there a reason to why 2 objects with the same parameters are having different behaviours?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Basically, I'm new to programming (and to stackoverflow) and trying to learn the basics on p5.js.
I'm one of the guys trying Pong out and diving in how to create different levels of difficulty I discovered that 2 balls who supposedly should have the same radius actually don't (fact that messes up my hitboxes) and using the same constant to change the Y axis'speed results in 2 completely different Y speeds. I'm almost sure I know where the problem is, but I have zero clue on why it happens, in any case I will leave a link for the full thing [here](http://editor.p5js.org/Nicolas_Birrer/sketches/fzXgJLPyg).

I made a second ball to make the opponent's paddle follow it's path and I'm pretty sure the problem is either in getting the ball's y position or in how I use it after that, since when I comment those out the thing works how I would like it to.

```
class Ball {
   constructor(_x, _y, _radius, _xSpeed, _ySpeed, _color){
      this.x = _x;
      this.y = _y;
      this.radius = _radius;
      this.xSpeed = _xSpeed;
      this.ySpeed = _ySpeed;
      this.color = _color;
   }

   //this guy is one of my suspects
   get ballY() {
      return this.y += this.ySpeed;
   }

   show() {
      fill(this.color)
      circle(this.x, this.y, 2 * this.radius); 
      fill(255)
   }
   moveY() {
      this.y += this.ySpeed;
   }

//leaving it here for context
class Paddle {
  constructor(_x, _y, _length, _height, _tag) {
    this.x = _x
    this.y = _y
    this.length = _length
    this.height = _height
    this.tag = _tag
  }

  //with this guy also in the list
  get opSpeed() {
    return ball2.ballY - this.y - 45;
  }

  //or maybe here
   move() {
      if(this.tag == "opponent") {
      this.y += this.opSpeed;
     }
   }
```

I would appreciate anyone who could give some light in the matter, thanks.

Comment: Why is the paddle hard coded to ball2?

Comment: To be completely honest because I couldn't think of a better way of doing it. And specially to ball2 to try messing up with it's velocities and create a somewhat reasonable difficulty, since making it hard coded to ball1 is either pretty easy or straight up impossible to beat.

Comment: This is likely your source of error, since both paddles will update the ball

Comment: I see, is there any way of doing it without hard coding it or making both update the ball? A different getter or something.

Comment: pass the ball to hit into the constructor